# set verbose in command Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I can set verbosity of my command with

```
php bin/console mycommand:command -vvv
```

How can i Set the same value with --verbose? [2.3 symfony](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-great-new-features-in-the-console-component)

```
php bin/console mycommand:command --verbose=3
```

I have this error

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--verbose" option does not accept a value.
```

With  helper I can see this option

> -v|vv|vvv, --verbose                Increase the verbosity of
>   messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for
>   debug

Comment: Strange... It should, according to the doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/usage.html#global-options

Comment: @Veve with only `--verbose` i get `OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE`

Comment: maybe is it a Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I digged into the code and it seems to be a bug in the console component (I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it actually is a bug). The `--verbose` option is defined with a value of `InputOption::VALUE_NONE`, indicating it is not allowing any values.</strike>

I created a bug report here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18546

It is a bug in the documentation of symfony and is not supported. Use `-v`, `-vv` or `-vvv` respectively (see the answer in my bug report).